# backend suddenly stopped working and threw this error "Cannot find module '../../cast/boolean'"

Tags: javascript, node.js

A day before my project was working fine the next day this showed up when I ran nodemon command:

```
module.js:471

        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module '../../cast/boolean'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (h:\Backend\notecrates_backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\operators\exists.js:3:21)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I run my project on visual studio and I closed visual studio directly
while my project was running may be this caused the problem??

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules` and try running `npm install`

Comment: This command is not running in windows can you be specific for windows

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules` means simply to remove node_modules folder

Comment: @Hellstellar He means delete the node_modules folder from the project root. In windows, if you use **powershell**, type `rm node_modules`. if you use **cmd**, type `rmdir node_modules /s`

Comment: @Hellstellar Could you post the line where you have imported that file using require?